Unity - Skipped rendering frame because GfxDevice is in invalid
In the Unity 2022 build for Android with AR, I found an error:
"Skipped rendering frame because GfxDevice is in invalid"
Accompanied by a frozen loading screen.
I found a couple of discussions about the same error, but no solution to the problem.
I would like to ask people who managed to fix this error to share a simple solution here.
You have now found a solution.:

Remove "Magic Leap XR Plugin"
Delete Libs
Restart Unity

Hope it helps others.
